# Screen randomly turns black and closes an application

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card

I have an HP EliteBook 840 G2
It looks like this:
[*My Laptop*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHONg.jpg)

Here are the specs:

CPU: *Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz* Its maximum is 3.10GHz

GPU: *Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500*

RAM: 8.0 GB DDR3

Now the actual problem is that the screen goes off at random times! For example today I was writing a program in a Python IDE called Pycharm and the only other applications which were open were *OneNote 2013* and a folder(Which is not an application). Now all of a sudden the screen goes black for a few seconds. Then it's fine again but Pycharm, the IDE from earlier is closed! And when I open Chrome or Edge it gives me an error because there's not enough memory. After that, there is a weird square in the middle of the screen. I am assuming its a graphics problem but how do I make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: All drivers up to date?

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 do you use? 1903, 1909 or 2004? (2004 has some known problems with Intel Graphics).

Comment: @spikey_richie I installed the HP support assistant few weeks back so it should be fine. Otherwise i haven't got any other driver

Comment: @Robert I got version 1909

Comment: *"And when I open Chrome or Edge it gives me an error because there's not enough memory."* - Have you looked at  the actual memory usage of your system and all your processes? Also, I might consider having a look at your Windows [virtual memory](https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2016/05/10/how-to-manage-windows-10-virtual-memory.aspx) settings. Whether this is entirely a graphics driver issue or not, it might be worthwhile to investigate.

Comment: ok, i will check